# Resample panda time series to have the end time stamp for the bin name?

Tags: python, pandas

I generate a sample 5 minute time series:

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=10, freq='5T')
data=range(10)
ser = pd.Series(data, index=index)
```

What it looks like:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0.0
2000-01-01 00:05:00    1.0
2000-01-01 00:10:00    2.0
2000-01-01 00:15:00    3.0
2000-01-01 00:20:00    4.0
2000-01-01 00:25:00    5.0
2000-01-01 00:30:00    6.0
2000-01-01 00:35:00    7.0
2000-01-01 00:40:00    8.0
2000-01-01 00:45:00    9.0
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```

**What I need**

I would like to turn this time series into a 15 minute one and have each 15 minute value be the mean of the 5 minute values observed in that 15 min period, i.e.

```
2000-01-01 00:15:00    2.0   # i.e. mean(1, 2, 3)
2000-01-01 00:30:00    5.0   # i.e. mean(4, 5, 6)
2000-01-01 00:45:00    8.0   # i.e. mean(7, 8, 9)
```

**Things I tried**

If I resample this data into 15 minute buckets and call mean i get:

```
ser.resample('15T').mean()

2000-01-01 00:00:00    1.0
2000-01-01 00:15:00    4.0
2000-01-01 00:30:00    7.0
2000-01-01 00:45:00    9.0
```

which is not computing the means I want. If I add `closed='right'` to the resample call I get closer to the values I want but the timestamps are not right.

```
ser.resample('15T', closed='right').mean()
1999-12-31 23:45:00    0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:00    2.0
2000-01-01 00:15:00    5.0
2000-01-01 00:30:00    8.0
Freq: 15T, dtype: float64
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could just do ser.index = ser.index + dt.timedelta(0, 15 * 60) to add 15 minutes onto your index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `label` argument in [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample),

```
ser.resample('15T', label='right', closed='right').mean()
```

this shifts the label from the left (default) to the right of the resampled window. This is a more succinct than my somewhat clunky comment.